# What does Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE do?

Tags: android, vibration

How does `Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE` work? If I set:

```
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

what's going to happen?

The documentation is not clear. How can I make the phone vibrating if and only if the vibrate-option for the native sms application or for the call is set to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add following permition for enabling vibrate.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
```

And for detecting vibrate mode you can use AudioManager's [getRingerMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode%28%29) method

```
    AudioManager audiomanager = (AudioManager)
                                getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    switch (audiomanager.getRingerMode()) {
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
            Log.i("Mode","Silent mode");
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
            Log.i("Mode","Vibrate mode");
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
            Log.i("Mode","Normal mode");
            break;
    }
```

**EDIT**

You can check user's vibrate settings of call and notification using following code

```
Log.i("Setting", ""+audiomanager.shouldVibrate(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER));
Log.i("Setting", ""+audiomanager.shouldVibrate(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
```

Comment: Thank you. Is therea way to know the setting for the sms?

Comment: The original question was: How can I make the phone vibrating if and only if the vibrate-option for the native sms application or for the call is set to true?

Comment: there is another setting that is normally accessible from the native sms applciation do decide whether you want the phone tovibrate in case an sms is received

Comment: Please also consider that when the mode is normal there is often another flag to say whether you want the phone to vibrate for new notifications etc

Comment: Note that [shouldVibrate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#shouldVibrate%28int%29) was deprecated in API level 16. Use [getRingerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode%28%29) instead.